# How can I remove specific item from List when data in firebase realtime db is removed?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

When a data in realtime database is removed, I want to remove the data from list as well. I wrote following code, but it does not work. 
Is there anybody can help me?

```
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            TodoItem todoItem = dataSnapshot.getValue(TodoItem.class);
            todoItems.add(todoItem);
            adapter.setTodoItems(todoItems);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            TodoItem todoItem = dataSnapshot.getValue(TodoItem.class);
            todoItems.remove(todoItem);
            adapter.setTodoItems(todoItems);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to keep the keys of the TODO items from the database in `onChildAdded`. Then when `onChildRemoved` gets called, you can look up the position of the item by its key and remove it from the `todoItems` list based on its position.

So in `onChildAdded`:

```
todoItems.add(todoItem);
todoItemKeys.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
```

And then in `onChildRemoved`:

```
int index = todoItemKeys.indexOf(dataSnapshot.getKey());
todoItems.remove(index);
todoItemKeys.remove(index);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
This is what I wanted to know.   
In my code, I initialized 'todoItemKeys' as below and tried the solution. It works~
`final List<String> todoItemsKeys = new ArrayList<>();`